# Delete Many-To-Many relations in Graph EF7

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to way to automatically remove many-to-many relationships in a detached entity in a graph/aggregate root in Entity Framework Core. I have tried with DBContext.Update() but that doesn't delete entries that no longer exists in the detached model.

The scenario is an angular app that sends a Project object as json to a web API. This works when new project owners are added to the project but not when they are removed. Since I'm sending the whole project as one object and the ProjectOwnerUser entries that still are in the database are missing in the project when they are removed at the client I'm guessing that EF can't set the EntityState to deleted. One solution is to get the model from the database and then manually compare them and remove the ProjectOwnerUser entities that no longer exists in the model form the client but I'm hoping for a more generic solution...

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectUserOwners> ProjectUserOwners { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectUserOwners> ProjectUserOwners { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectUserOwners
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem.
I had to turn off Deletes to get the model to build.
Now when I try to remove I get this error:

The association between entity types 'Case' and 'EmployeeCase' has been severed but the foreign key for this relationship cannot be set to null.
If the dependent entity should be deleted, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.